# Why i am not able to get Advertisement packets or any information?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, tizen, tizen-web-app

Advertise through scan chip: Why chip is not able to broadcast data. We scan chip through Service uuid - tizen web module. Is it platform issue ?

SDK: Tizen Wearable 2.3.2

Platform : Web API

Samsung Gear S2, Version2.3.2

**code explanation :** After scanned chip call advertise() not get any info. so we call advertise() when user press connect button. This is demo code.

```
//button for connet
function connect() {
var contentText = document.querySelector('#content-text-connect');

console.log("" + contentText.innerHTML);

adapter.startScan(onDeviceFound);

console.log("start scanning");

advertise();

}

function onDeviceFound(device) {

var d_name = device.name + "";
console.log("Found device-" + d_name);

if (d_name !== null && (d_name.substring(0, 11) === "FreeXip BGM")) {

    remoteDevice = device;

    console.error("Found device name: " + device.name);

    adapter.stopScan();
    console.log("connectSuccess - stop scanning");


    //advertise();

    connectToChip(remoteDevice);

  }
}
function advertise(){

   var advertiseData = new tizen.BluetoothLEAdvertiseData(
            {
              includeName: true,
              serviceuuids: ["0bd51666-e7cb-469b-8e4d-2742f1ba77cc"]  /* 180F is 16bit Battery Service UUID   */
            });
    var connectable = true;
    var adapter = tizen.bluetooth.getLEAdapter();

    adapter.startAdvertise(advertiseData, "ADVERTISE",
            function onstate(state)
            {
              console.log("Advertising configured: " + state);
              alert("Advertising configured="+state);
            },

            function(error)
            {
              console.log("startAdvertise() failed: " + error.message);
              alert("startAdvertise() failed="+ error.message);
            },

            "LOW_LATENCY", connectable);
  }
}
[![Output when we run this code][1]][1]
```

Reference : ()
[Tizen Dev guidelines](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/connectivity-and-wireless/bluetooth#add_adv_data)

Any suggestion it would be great. Thanks :)

Comment: Why are you giving Native app guide ? And you posted about web app problem !

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get BLE advertisement packet of other devices by Web API?

You can see that below reference guide.
[Discovering Bluetooth Low Energy Devices](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/connectivity-and-wireless/bluetooth#Discovering_BT_LE_Devices)

Your posted reference is natvie guide and your goal is ambiguous.

Here is Web API reference about Bluetooth, Tizen 2.3.2. I recommend you take a look at the API documentation and try again.
[Bluetooth API](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.2/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/wearable/tizen/bluetooth.html)

Good luck :)